# eclipse error exporting plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, imp

I'm getting a strange error when trying to export an IMP plugin from eclipse.
When using eclipse indigo I get:

```
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:88: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\ide\build.xml:293: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\ide\build.xml:368: Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\ide\build.xml:293: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shachar\workspace jee\ide\build.xml:368: Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

The same error appears when I use eclipse indigo rcp & rap version.

For the same reason I can't create an update site for the plugin.

This error doesn't seem to happen in eclipse jee version. While the export succeeds,
the plugin itself doesn't work (and it does work when I run the project).

Comment: @MattCrinklaw-Vogt Looks like the path of workspace contains 'space' character. Try a workspace without space.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue.  Re-installing the "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment" plugin ended up fixing it for me.

Comment: I think the missing package is org.eclipse.pde.api.tools at least that seemed to be the missing package when i ran into this recently. I solved it simply by adding PDE in Help -> Install New Software..."